# Erro ao compilar um arquivo *.dpr no Delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7

Estou tentando compilar um arquivo *.dpr no Delphi 7, porém sempre quado ele começa a compilar ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E se aperto OK e executo de novo ele exibe outra janela  de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sou novo em Delphi, alguém sabe o que poderia estar causando isso?

Comment: Boa tarde, podes dar mais informações? Qual banco de dados você está usando (`FireBird`, `MySQL`, `Oracle`, `Access`)? Qual componente de conexão (`IBX`, `ADO`, `FireDAC`)? Como você informa ao componente os dados para realizar a conexão (_Arquivo INI, dados fixos_)? E devo acrescentar que provavelmente você deve estar usando o `FireBird` e serviço do mesmo está parado.

Comment: @Andrey Boa tarde, eu estou utilizando no momento o FireBird, na verdade essa aplicação não criada por mim, porém preciso mudar o banco de dados de FIreBird para PostGreSQL, essa aplicação utiliza de um arquivo *.ini para fazer a conexão com o Banco de Dados, por isso iria tentar ver no código onde essa conexão com o arquivo ocorre, porém sempre que tento executar o erro descrito ocorre.

Comment: E o serviço do banco de dados `FireBird` está iniciado? E antes de mais nada, está instalado? Veja no **Painel de controle**. Ta com cara de ser isso.

Comment: @Andrey Questão de banco está tudo OK, está instalado e rodando normalmente

Comment: O componente de conexão com o banco de dados já está habilitado? Provavelmente propriedade Active... se estiver, desabilite-o.

Comment: Descobri o que era, a linha que fazia a conexão com o arquivo .ini estava comentada, dai quando tirei o comentario deu tudo certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o que era, a linha que fazia a conexão com o arquivo .ini estava comentada, dai quando tirei o comentário deu tudo certo